# Fast API with Dependency-injector Python getting strategy_service.test(Test(name, id)) AttributeError: 'Provide' object has no attribute 'test'

Tags: python-3.x, dependency-injection, rest, fastapi

I am using FastApI and dependency-injetor
below is the project structure

> ```
> -app 
>     - api/v1/endpoints
>     - repository
>     - service
>     main.py
> ```

When I am injecting the dependencies to the endpoints I always gets Provide object not actual class object due to this code always throws

**AttributeError: 'Provide' object has no attribute 'test'**
However if I inject the dependencies in normal function it works well.

Here is below code snippet that I am using -

users.py as endpoint

```
@router.get('/u/{name}/{id}')
def add_user(name:str, id:int, strategy_service:StrategyService = Depends(Provide[Container.strategy_service])):
    strategy_service.test(Test(name, id))
```

Container - class

```
class Container(DeclarativeContainer):
    #Define configuration
    config = providers.Configuration()

    #Database
    db = providers.Singleton(Database, db_url=config.db_url)
    
    #All the repositories Configuration
    strategy_repository = providers.Factory(
        StrategyRepository,
        session_factory = db.provided.session
    )

#All the services configured
    strategy_service = providers.Factory(
        StrategyService,
        strategy_repository = strategy_repository
    )
```

main.py

```
    def create_app() -> FastAPI:
        container = Container()
        container.config.from_yaml('../config.yml')
         container.wire(packages=[api])
   
    
        app = FastAPI()
    
        app.container = container
    
        #Here configure all your routes
        app.include_router(api_v1.router, prefix='/api/v1')
    
        #Return the final app
        return app
    
    app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #We can get this host and port number from config files
    uvicorn.run(app, host = '127.0.0.1', port = 8080)
```

Getting this exception -

> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File
> "/Users/manpr06/driveE/AlgoBot/algotradersbot-service/app/api/v1/endpoints/users.py",
> line 21, in add_user
> strategy_service.test(Test(name, id)) AttributeError: 'Provide' object has no attribute 'test'

Can someone please help one this?

Comment: Where does this `Provide` object come from, and why do you wrap your dependency inside it?

Comment: I am using dependency-injector library to manage the dependency across the project. This library provided this.

Comment: It's impossible to say how you should solve this when you don't link which library you're using or how that object is supposed to be used; now you're injecting a dependency injection library, instead of injecting the actual dependency. I'm not sure why you would need multiple layers of dependency injection; it seems like the solution would to either drop the second layer, make the dependency you inject resolve the actual dependency (inject a dependency that resolve Provide) or resolve the Provide object inside your view function

Answer (score 4):

Seems in your `main.py`, your wiring configuration is wrong,

```py
    def create_app() -> FastAPI:
        container = Container()
        container.config.from_yaml('../config.yml')
         container.wire(packages=[api])
```

you need to write the correct path like this:

```py
         container.wire(packages=["api.v1.endpoints"])
```

---

FYI:

I faced the same issue but resolved with above way, let me share the summary of my codes:

```
├── core
│   └── di
│       └── __init__.py
└── handler
    └── cluster
        └── v1
            └── cluster.py
```

`__init__.py`

```py
class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):

    wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(modules=["handler.cluster.v1.cluster"])

    cluster_repo = providers.Factory(***)

    cluster_service = providers.Factory(
        ClusterService,
        cluster_repo=cluster_repo
    )
```

`cluster.py`

```py
cluster_router = APIRouter()

@cluster_router.get(
    "/",
    response_model=List[ClusterSummaryResponse],
    responses={"404": {"model": ExceptionResponseSchema}},
    summary="List Cluster",
)
@inject
async def list_cluster(cluster_service: ClusterService = Depends(Provide[Container.cluster_service]), type = None):
    return await cluster_service.list(type=type)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need setup wiring

```
class Container(DeclarativeContainer):
    wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(
        modules=["src.routes.v1.users"] # or "users" in your case
    )

    # Define configuration
    config = providers.Configuration()
```

Comment: why do you need wiring? Wiring is already setup in main.py

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is directly related but after I downgraded dependency-injector from 4.39.1 to 4.38.0 it solved this issue and started working. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `@inject` decorator on your endpoint